# Complex Nested Linq Query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm looking to find all expense reports that are in a submitted state and were submitted prior to a given date ("days").
Is there a better (faster, easier, cleaner) way to do this?

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days);
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var data = context.tExpenseReports
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(r => context.tTransactionStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TransactionStatusID == r.tTransactions.Max(t => t.TransactionStatusID)) != null ?
                                context.tTransactionStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TransactionStatusID == r.tTransactions.Max(t => t.TransactionStatusID)).TransactionStatusID == IDConstants.TRANSACTION_STATUS_SUBMITTED &&
                                context.tTransactionHistories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TransactionStatusID == r.tTransactions.Max(t => t.TransactionStatusID)).CreatedDatetime < startDate
                                : false)
              .Execute()
              .Select(Mapper.Map<tExpenseReport,ExpenseReport>)
              .ToArray();
              return data;
          }
    }
```

Comment: the requirement expressed in words seems simple but your query is made complicated, looks like you have a wrong design. Also it's better to show your related models for better understanding (to query it in a different way). There should be `one-one` relationship between `ExpenseReport` table and another table containing all submitted reports. After imported, the entity `ExpenseReport` should have a non null navigation property referencing the entry in the submitted table. About the create time, unless one report has multiple create time, we can make a column right inside ExpenseReport instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand all your methods

But I think it will work

```
var sata1=( from r in context.tExpenseReports.AsNoTracking()
                       let max = r.tTransactions.Max(t => t.TransactionStatusID)
                       let s = context.tTransactionStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TransactionStatusID == max)
                       where s!=null
                       where s.CreatedDatetime < startDate

                       select r);
          return  sata1 .Execute()
              .Select(Mapper.Map<tExpenseReport,ExpenseReport>)
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You didn't include the tTransactionHistories, but when I added them in the same fashion, the query does return the same result set. Example: let h = context.tTransactionHistories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TransactionStatusID == r.tTransactions.Max(t => t.TransactionStatusID))
                    where s != null && h != null

Comment: In your example you should write `let h = context.tTransactionHistories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TransactionStatusID ==max)`